# Derby Java NoRouteToHostException: Error connecting to server ... on port ... with message No route to host: connect;

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, client-server, derby

I am writing an Application with a Derby Database Server and multiple clients can access the server.
To start the Network server I use the commandline-Tool:

> startNetworkServer -h 192.168.2.1

With ij-tool I create a Database and some users according to the derby security guide:

> connect 'jdbc:derby:testdb;create=true;user=tquist'; 
>   call SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER( 'tquist', 'tquist' ); 
>   call SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER( 'thardy', 'thardy' );

The clients `connect` to the database, create a table if not exists and then do an `insert` and `shutdown` the database. They do this repeatedly.

When I only connect a single client to the database it works well.
When I try to connect a second client to the database then on one client there is an error:

> State 08001 NoRouteToHostException Error connecting to server xxx on port xxx with message No route to host:connect;

and another error arises:

> State 08003 No current connection

The second problem is:
If I want to connect to the same database `testdb` with the user `tquist` and in the other client I use the user `thardy` then they will use a different Database scheme and use their own tables instead of one single table.
What am I doing wrong if I want different users to connect to the same database accessing the same table, instead of each user uses its own tables.

Comment: That's a lot of different questions in one question! And a number of them are very basic. May I suggest that you start by working through the Derby tutorials: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/getstart/

Comment: _... If multiple clients are accessing the database and one client shuts down the database, the remaining clients will encounter a failure the next time they attempt an SQL command._ That was the Problem of the first question. So I only shutdown the database, when in embedded mode. Now this works!

Comment: For the second question:`CREATE SCHEMA SCHEMA_NAME` and `SET SCHEMA SCHEMA_NAME`. And then for the users GRANT SELECT TO user1, etc...

Comment: Excellent! Seems like you are making good progress. Please feel free to open new separate questions with precise issues as you gain more familiarity with the software.